# Add bullet controls to a tabbed slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

Here's hoping someone know how to do this. I am new to programming and haven't been able to figure it out or find the answer anywhere else. What i am trying to do is add a secondary control to an existing tabbed slideshow. The secondary control will be linked bullets that become active and inactive just like the existing links do as the slideshow plays and on click.

You can see an example of what I have here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZSPX3/1/. The jquery code follows. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 var HM = {
    //tab
    jqs_slideList: '.slideList',
    jqs_tabList: '.slides .carouselLinks',


    init: function() {
        //init sliders
        var aSliders = $(this.jqs_slideList);
        if (aSliders.length > 0) {
            this.slideShow(aSliders);
        }

        //init the carousels that are lists of links
        $('.carousel.icons').hellmannsCrsl({
            rotateSpeed: 5000,
            viewport: '.carouselLinks'
        });
    },

    slideShow: function(eSlideListParam) {
        var slideList = eSlideListParam,
            slides = slideList.find('li'),
            tabList = slideList.siblings('.carouselLinks'),
            tabs = tabList.find('li'),
            speed = 500;


        tabs.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            $(this).trigger('slides.swap');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        //make it automatic, but this doesn't work properly, I'm stuck...
        setInterval(function() {
            var current = parseInt($('li.selected a').data('links-to').split('_')[1],10);
            var idx=current-1;
            var max = $('.carouselLinks li a').length;
            idx = (current<max) ? (idx+1):0;
            $('a:eq('+idx+')').trigger('click');
        }, 3000);

        /**
         * This is where the animation, i.e. fade, is performing.
         * I find it quite convenient to use bind/trigger principle as it's easier to maintain
         */
        tabs.find('a').bind('slides.swap', function() {
            var self = $(this),
                selfIndex = self.parent().index(),
                targetSlide = slides.eq(selfIndex);

            //fade in/out slides
            slides.filter('.active').stop(true, false).fadeOut(speed, function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
            targetSlide.stop(true, false).fadeIn(speed).addClass('active');

            tabs.removeClass('selected');
            self.parent().addClass('selected');
        });
    }
};

HM.init();
```

Comment: So, where is the error?

Comment: There's no error. I just want to add the bullets control as well as the links.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/sr8e7/)

**HTML**

```
<!-- bullet ctrl -->
<div class="bulletLinks">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-links-to="slide_1" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="selected"><a data-links-to="slide_2" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a data-links-to="slide_3" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a data-links-to="slide_4" href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /bullet ctrl -->
```

**CSS**

```
.bulletLinks a {
  background: #900; // Or bullet background image
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.bulletLinks a:hover {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**jQuery** Code edits

```
tabList = slideList.siblings('.carouselLinks, .bulletLinks'),
```

Comment: @mdesmdv This is great!! Thank you so much. Is there anyway to have the links on the side become active when the bullets are used.

Comment: There is always a way, I tried yesterday but...I'll see later what I can do ;)

Comment: I wonder if it would be easier to work in the other direction. Would you be able to add tabbed titles to this example and have the titles switch to active and inactive http://jsfiddle.net/vperou/JrzHM/